# Highlight all occurrences of a selected object with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, resharper, add-in

I was used to use RockScroll (or MetalScroll), but when I started to use ReSharper my RockScroll start to show some bugs. Well, this is scope to another discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089493/is-rockscroll-compatible-with-resharper.

But my problem is related, because now without MetalScroll I can't highlight all occurrences, what I consider very useful in many situations.

Someone have another plugin for VS2010 or for ReSharper that do the same or better?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are looking for "Highlight usages in file" This can be access via **<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>** or **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>** depending if you are using VS key bindings or InteliJ bindings. Use either **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd>** or **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp/PageDown</kbd>** to go to next and previous highlights.

You can also use the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>** combo to bring up a menu of what to jump to. This can be used to move the cursor to the next occurrence.

Comment: I think one of these shortcuts might be mistaken.  The default Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 keybinding to navigate between highlighted occurrences (when Tools > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > "Highlight references to symbol under cursor" is enabled) is CTRL+SHIFT+Up/Down.

Comment: Its very troublesome to press this key combination every time where most IDEs do this on double clicking the word. Try the VS extension RockMargin mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools). There are other versions, at least one for [Visual Studio 2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2013) and another one for Visual Studio 2015.

It plays nicely with ReSharper and has this selected text matches highlighting both in the editor and the scrollbars among many other features.

Answer (score 0):

Try the visual studio extension [RockMargin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1b0d7360-40dd-447e-8bef-90e2cf52f683/view/Reviews/2) which highlight the occurrences on double click (like most IDEs). Works fine with VS 2015 and ReSharper.

Comment: For VS2015 there's [RockMargin2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=swaxx.RockMargin2015). But it overrides the map-mode scrollbar with its own (inferior) implementation and changes theme colors. Would be great to have an extension that better plays with the IDE