# What is the equivalent shortcut for CTRL + D ("add selection to next location match") of VSCode in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

VSCode has a very useful shortcut: `CTRL + D` - Add Selection To Next Find Match.

What is the equivalent in Visual Studio?

Below an example:

[image: CTRL+D VSCode shortcut]

Comment: Do you want go to the next search result? F3

Comment: I added now an image demonstrating an example of using CTRL + D

No, although the "next result search" has a similar effect, "add selection to next find match" allows editing according to the example I put in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no equivalent directly in Visual Studio, but you can use [Select Next Occurrence](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thomaswelen.SelectNextOccurrence) extension that mimics this behavior.

Answer (score 17):

#### Update Visual Studio 2017+

This is natively available starting in Visual Studio 2017 under the command(s):

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> - **`Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret`**
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> - **`Edit.InsertCaretsatAllMatching`**

You can change the shortcut in [keyboard options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKX3z.png) if you want.

[image: select next]

#### Comparison VS Code and Visual Studio

| Visual Studio Code | Visual Studio |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch` **Add Selection to Next Find Match** | <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> `Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret` |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> `editor.action.selectHighlights` **Select All Occurrences of Find Match** | <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> `Edit.InsertCaretsAtAllMatching` |

#### Further Reading

- [Multiple select in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16495727/1366033)
- [Highlight all occurrences of a selected object with ReSharper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3009604/1366033)

Answer (score 4):

I figure out  that this feature (Multi-Caret Support) was added through an update in Visual Studio 2017.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> you can add multiple insertion points or carets, as shown here [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improving-your-productivity-in-the-visual-studio-editor/).