# How to use the "Select next occurrence" feature with Resharper in VS 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

On Resharper's documentation I found out that this feauture can be used with "Alt + J" shortcut. But when I select the name of some variable and click foregoing shortcut nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this tracking issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-478461) - this doesn't appear to be currently supported by resharper.

However, starting with VS 2017, there is a native command that will select the next matching text:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> - **`Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret`**

[image: select next]

**See Also**: [What is the equivalent shortcut for CTRL + D of VSCode in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70379900/1366033)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your extensions, sometimes there are conflicting Shortcuts.

You can have a look at the Visual Studio Shortcuts at
Tools | Options | Environment and then Keyboard

Have a look at the complete Tutorial here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Configuring_Keyboard_Shortcuts.html